# Updating specific map index with new value

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey I am trying to update a specific map index in firestore with a new timestamp in the daysCompleted array.
My issue is I don't understand how to update for example the daysCompleted array of the first map (index 0)(or the second index 1). I tried to freestyle something like this, but obviously it didn't work:

```
 func updateDaysComplete(){
    db.collection("users").document(currentUser!.uid).updateData([
        "activeChallenges[\(0)].daysCompleted": FieldValue.arrayUnion([Timestamp()])
    ])
}
```

This is the firebase structure:
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There is no way to update an item in an array by its index in Firestore. You'll have to load the entire array, change it in application code, and write the entire array back to the document.

Comment: Another way to think of it:  what Firestore calls an "array" everyone else would call "an ordered list" - it has an order, but not an index.